# Can't install VLC package from the PPA "The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available"

Tags: apt

Since I installed Ubuntu I was unable to install video Codecs I get the following errors:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
        The following packages have unmet dependencies:

    gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
    gstreamer1.0-libav:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                             Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                             Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                             Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
                             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
```

However, I was using VLC. I had to uninstall VLC for a reason, now I'm unable to reinstall it. When I try to install VLC it gives me the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried all the solve for this kind of problems, none of the worked for me. I've also tried `aptitude` which also didn't worked. Installation from source also failed.

`apt-get update` gives me an error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A9653F936FD5529
```

Comment: Already tried. None of the solve worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the error with the signature. The solve was the following commands:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 6A9653F936FD5529
gpg --export --armor 6A9653F936FD5529 | sudo apt-key add -
```